# New ECL connector using integration framework showing error

Tags: ecl, sites-9.1, external-integrations, ecl-connector

I am trying to create a new ECL connector for the new dam system for sites 9.1. using the integration framework. I am following the blog created by @Niclas.

Suddenly I started getting the following error after uploading an updated package to add on service.
following is the error log:

### part1:

```
2020-09-11 19:29:37,960 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel GetStubSchemaId(publicationId='3')
2020-09-11 19:29:37,961 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel TryGetStubSchemaId(publicationId='3')
2020-09-11 19:29:37,962 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel GetStubFolderId(publicationUri='tcm:0-3-1')
2020-09-11 19:29:37,962 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel GetStubFolderId:stubConfig.Id='tcm:3-8496-2'
2020-09-11 19:29:37,994 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel GetStubSchemaId(publicationId='3')
2020-09-11 19:29:37,995 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel TryGetStubSchemaId(publicationId='3')
2020-09-11 19:29:37,995 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel GetStubFolderId(publicationUri='tcm:0-3-1')
2020-09-11 19:29:37,996 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] INFO  DomainModel GetStubFolderId:stubConfig.Id='tcm:3-8496-2'
2020-09-11 19:29:38,004 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] ERROR DomainModel 
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:10'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:10'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EnsureInputClosed(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.CloseChannel()
2020-09-11 19:29:38,005 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [31] ERROR DomainModel 
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Tridion.Infrastructure.Core.Exceptions.LocalizableConfigurationErrorsException: No External Content Library provider with the name widen_connectorConnector version 1.0.0 is available.
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.EclProviders.GetProvider(IMountPointConfiguration mountPointConfiguration)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(IMountPointConfiguration config, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.<>c__DisplayClass56_1.<Mount>b__3(Object <p0>)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.Dispose()
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.Dispose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceProvider.ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Object instance)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Object instance)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Tridion.Infrastructure.Core.Exceptions.LocalizableConfigurationErrorsException: No External Content Library provider with the name widen_connectorConnector version 1.0.0 is available.
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.EclProviders.GetProvider(IMountPointConfiguration mountPointConfiguration)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(IMountPointConfiguration config, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.<>c__DisplayClass56_1.<Mount>b__3(Object <p0>)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Tridion.Infrastructure.Core.Exceptions.LocalizableConfigurationErrorsException: No External Content Library provider with the name widen_connectorConnector version 1.0.0 is available.
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.EclProviders.GetProvider(IMountPointConfiguration mountPointConfiguration)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(IMountPointConfiguration config, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
<---
```

---

2nd part:

---

```
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
2020-09-11 19:29:44,909 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [81] INFO  Tridion.Remoting Tridion.Remoting channel 1 changed state Stopped.
2020-09-11 19:29:44,909 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [81] INFO  Tridion.Remoting Starting Tridion.Remoting channel 1 the remoting add-in D:\Tridion\Addons\RepositoryCache\TcmServiceHost\A6D8924BD60D1E8A80B1142A635D26BC\widen_connectorConnector.dll.
2020-09-11 19:29:44,910 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [81] INFO  Tridion.Remoting Tridion.Remoting channel 1 changed state Starting.
2020-09-11 19:29:46,330 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [30] INFO  widen_connectorConnector Configuration: Page Size = 3
2020-09-11 19:29:46,332 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [39] INFO  widen_connectorConnector initialize
2020-09-11 19:29:46,355 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [68] INFO  widen_connectorConnector start
2020-09-11 19:29:46,356 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [30] INFO  widen_connectorConnector DownloadBinaryService
2020-09-11 19:29:46,359 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [41] INFO  widen_connectorConnector GetFileService start
2020-09-11 19:29:46,696 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
2020-09-11 19:29:46,697 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
2020-09-11 19:29:46,698 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
2020-09-11 19:29:46,698 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
2020-09-11 19:29:46,699 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: UnityEngine, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
2020-09-11 19:29:46,700 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: Xamarin.iOS, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
2020-09-11 19:29:46,700 6232_TcmServiceHost_1   [67] WARN  FolderAssemblyLoadContext dotnet(9568): Failed to load: Mono.Android, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

---

Even if try to load default package without any customization still its showing similar error.

Comment: The first error is more of communication issue can you make sure you are able to communicate with ECL endpoint.Also can you provide more details on the connectors that you are using which DAM.

Comment: Can you refer to this link for more details - https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/developing-connectors-using-the-new-tridion-integration-framework

Comment: @AnandNS: i am following same blog.

Comment: soumava sarkar , are you still facing this issue

Comment: @AnandNS: i have overcome it. issue was not time out. its generic error shown by connector framework if any error present. proper logging is only solution to understand the root cause

Answer (score -2):

i have overcome it. issue was not time out. its generic error shown by connector framework if any error present. proper logging is only solution to understand the root cause

Comment: Can you add an example of "proper logging" so that others can follow your lead if they have the same issue?

Comment: @NunoLinhares: that will be a good idea. let me work on it so that i can explain with code snippet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3476)

Comment: Still planning to provide an update?